# What do gateway and destination represent in Linux Networking?

Tags: linux, networking

My netstat gives me

```
netstat -r
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
default         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 enp3s0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 enp3s0
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 enp3s0
192.168.27.0    *               255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 vmnet8
192.168.129.0   *               255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 vmnet1
```

A route is a defined pair of addresses which represent the destination and a gateway.But what do they represent,does this mean that I send my parcel(email or whatever) from gateway or not?What does link-local represent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The address represents a network, and the gateway is the IP you communicate via to reach that particular network. When the gateway is an asterisk, it means that you're directly connected to that network, so a gateway is not needed.

When it comes to your specific scenario of the parcel/e-mail, it means that it is sent via the gateway in question. If no other routes match the destination, it is sent via the default gateway.

The link-local is a reference to the 169.254.0.0/16 subnet as defined by [RFC 3927](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3927), and is a non-routable subnet used in special circumstances, such as when no DHCP server is available.